# mail() not sending and returning a false

Tags: php, email

I have change my php.ini file and my sendmail.ini
As follows:

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like              Mercury
 SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port = 587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename 
mail.add_x_header=Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_mail.log"
```

From sendmail.ini:
i changed :

```
smtp_server= smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port= 587
smtp_ssl= auto
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=
auth_password=
```

In my mail.php :

```
 $send = mail('juntestingwebsite@gmail.com','Sample Mail','Sample content','From: example@example.com');

 if($send)
echo "yes";
else
echo "no";
```

So i set my settings and reseted XAMPP control panel and ran my mail.php file by going through localhost/mail.php 
It returns an error message of 'no' hence i know that it didnt send at all. Im using gmail. Any ideas on what could be wrong?
im new at this so any codes or help would be great!

Im using XAMPP version 3.2.1

Comment: Your ini file has no username and password filled in - did you remove them for the question, or does the actual file have them empty?

Comment: @andrewsi i have them filled up but left it empty for the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my sendmail.ini

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=25
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=yourgmailpassword
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

php/php.ini ----basically comment everything out except sendmail_path & mail.add_x_header

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = Off

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log = "C:\xampp\apache\logs\php_mail.log"
```

This worked for me after i updated the sendmail files (the old ones dont support smtp)

- go to http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ and grab the latest sendmail zip file
- unzip to desktop and copy the files into your \xampp\sendmail folder replacing everything that was there.EVERYTHING!
- Now open up sendmail.ini and copy paste what i showed above.(remove everything in that file first or just comment everything out!)
- NOTE: you dont need Mercury servers started for this.

Comment: ive just done this and it still returns a 'no' :(( i received a crash.txt file also in the sendmail folder. does that mean anything